# Confused with repect to working of GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

GridSearchCV implements a fit method in which it performs n-fold cross validation to determine best parameters. After this we can directly apply the best estimator to the testing data using predict() - Following this link : - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html

It says here "The model is trained on the full development set"

However we have only applied n fold cross validations here. Is the classifier somehow also training itself on the entire data? or is it just choosing the best trained estimator with best parameters amongst the n-folds when applying predict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `predict`, you'll need to set `'refit'` to `True`.  From the documentation:

```
refit : boolean
    Refit the best estimator with the entire dataset. 
    If “False”, it is impossible to make predictions using 
    this GridSearchCV instance after fitting.
```

It looks like it is true by default, so in the example, `predict` is based on the whole training set.